# Send email from office mail via javamail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am sending emails via gmail, but when I try to send emails from corporate mail I am get exception.

From company mail I can send email to another employees mail, but when I try to send to gmail account I get javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay exception.
How can I fix it?

Via gmail

```
    final String username = "mail goes here";
    final String password = "password goes here";

    final String to = "mail goes here";
    final String from = username;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(toGmail));
        message.setSubject("Test");
        message.setText("Testing");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Mail sent succesfully");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Via corporate mail

```
    final String toGmail = "test@gmail.com";
    final String toCompany = "one of employees mail goes here";
    final String from = "company's noreply mail goes here";
    final String to = toGmail;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "10.100.25.5");
    props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

   // props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   // props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   // props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Test");
        message.setText("Testing");
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Mail sent succesfully");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused about from where to where you want to send mails. Could you clarify that?

Comment: from corporate mait to gmail

Comment: Have you tried using the SMTP port 465?

Comment: I get DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "10.100.25.5", port 465, isSSL false

Comment: Depending of what is your corporate server and what filtering rules are implemented on it, it could be *by design*. Your best bet is to ask your mail admin about it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#norelay).  You're not authenticating to your corporate mail server so it's not letting you send messages outside the company.